# Why certain vbscript statements breaks with IE9+ whereas it works well on quirks mode?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, vbscript, quirks-mode

It is 'lu'ck replaced with 'su' when something goes wrong due to browser compatibility issues. Wondering why certain vbscript statements breaks in IE9+ whereas works well on quirks mode.

Following line simply gets value from a hidden field and assign it to a variable **data**. This is not working in IE9+ and throws an error *"SCRIPT258: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020102"*

```
data = frmSupplier.hdnData.value
```

Like wise For each statement is also breaking, where NodeList is collection of xml nodes loaded using "Microsoft.XMLDOM":

```
For Each Node In NodeList 
   ...
   ...
Next
```

There are couple of other cases as well. We tried below workarounds, but no luck.

Added `<!doctype html>` as per [Defining document compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Added `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">` as per [Specifying legacy document modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Please shed some light on this.

Comment: Please include the exact error message you receive.

Comment: bear in mind that (1) Quirks mode is an IE5 compatibility mode. That's *really* out of date; quirks mode really shouldn't even be a consideration these days. And (2) If you're using VBScript in the browser, your site will not work in any browser other than IE.

Comment: +1 Spudley, we are experiencing these issues with legacy application in ASP.

Comment: Tomalak, I am getting this error "SCRIPT258: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020102."

Answer (score 1):

There are the following issues with the script:

- [Dynamic properties are no longer supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537634)
- [XML data islands are no longer supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801224)
- [JScript Syntax Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by0atdkw)

**References**

- [Reference for Visual Basic Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa752043)